# How to put Google Drive or Dropbox on a network folder?

Tags: google-drive, google-workspace, dropbox

How to put Google Drive or Dropbox on a network folder?

If possible I would like to just put part of the folder on a network folder.

Comment: Since you're asking about the file syncing feature(s) rather than the web interface, your question is off-topic at [webapps.se] and should instead be asked at [su].

Answer (score 0):

You cannot put Google Drive on a network folder. The app does not accept it.

Comment: You can put Google Drive on a network folder if you use something like iSCSI that mounts the network drive like a local drive. Samba (SMB) shares though will not work. There some issues with network drives not sending notifications of file or folder changes that is required for Dropbox and Google Drive to work.